# Using BASH FOR LOOP and PARALLEL

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, gnu-parallel

Just want to check if this is possible to automate in **PRALLEL?**. I have a bash script that reads a **text file** line per line and then takes the word of that line as a parameter then it will be processed by the bash script. For sample this would be the format of the text file

**TEXT FILE**

```
# cat test.txt
dog
cat
fish
rat
dove
```

Then line per line will be executed by a separate bash script via loop fashion like these

```
# for word in `cat test.txt`; do ./MY-BASH-SCRIPT.sh ${word}; done
```

Well this works fine however I it is executed one by one. **May I ask for any suggestion on how can I possibly trigger the words in PRALLEL?** I've gone and also read the GNU Parallel and gone some test however got no luck yet

Comment: You can just use  **&**  `for word in $(cat test.txt); do (./MY-BASH-SCRIPT.sh ${word})&  done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is now solved via parallel command:

```
cat test.txt | parallel ./MY-BASH-SCRIPT.sh {}
```